# jQuery Mobile White HTML5 code bottom page error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

With the mobile jquery I have this problem , put a ListView in a subfolder and homepage , under the page , it appears as part of its html code in the screen that I put .
The DIV are affixed , in my opinion I lacks some script jquery Mobile

error screen:

[image]

Comment: tag your question with jquery mobile, add the screenshot inside your question, and the JQM code you have too to get a better idea where the issue is

Comment: i can't post image because ruputation